# How can i get an ID from a link?PHP

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

I have this link 
http://www.4allshop.nl/100133/acer-gold-15-6-traveler-3jr.html

and there are more links like this ,, i really want to get from every link the ID wish is 100133.
I tried it with cutting out from the left and the riht , but this isnt a solution becouse the character behind the ID are different with every link.
I really hope there is a simple solution to do this with a little PHP.

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: need more info. like all urls start from `http://www.4allshop.nl/`? id `100133` always after domain name? is there any url having `only ints between 2 /` like `/67867/`? try `explode('/',$url)[3]` it may also help. Always give maximum information to help you better and quicker... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex: `/http://www.4allshot\.com/([\d]+)/.*/`

```
$url = 'http://www.4allshop.nl/100133/acer-gold-15-6-traveler-3jr.html';
preg_match( '/http://www.4allshot\.com/([\d]+)/.*/', $url, $match );
var_dump( $match );
```

then use: `$match[1]` to get the ID

Comment: This did not work for me. I had to use `preg_match( '@^(?:http://www.4allshop.nl/)?([^/]+)@i', $url, $match );`

Comment: @SRing Why? What result did you got instead?

Comment: `Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '/' in /nfs/c01/h09/mnt/13953/domains/mydomain.php on line 3` and `$match[1]` came out `NULL`. Possibly I was doing something wrong.

Comment: @SRing I see, In PHP, all regex expressions start and end with a '/' character. That is why your expression didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Try Parsing out the String using parse_str.  Refer: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Comment: My suggestion of using parse_str was flawed.  Unless you have static domain and numeric paths, please use the following code.  

    $url = "http://www.4allshop.nl/100133/acer-gold-15-6-traveler-3jr.html";
    $path = explode("/", trim(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), "/"));